# Como trabalhar em equipe com o Git?

Tags: git, github, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Fork e Pull Requests ou contribuição direta dentro do repositório?

Estou iniciando um projeto no GitHub e sou iniciante em programação.
Quais são as melhores práticas para se trabalhar em equipes?
A contribuição direta pode ser feito por meio de criação de branchs para cada versão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou tentar resumir.

A primeira coisa é todo mundo tomar um tempo para estudar o Git e entender como funciona para não fazer besteira durante o versionamento, principalmente a sincronização entre repositórios locais e remotos.

Cada membro da equipe pode clonar o projeto (criar uma cópia local) e criar branches locais para diferentes finalidades de desenvolvimento (correções, novas funcionalidades) e mexer nelas.

Depois pode sincronizar com as branches remotas usando comandos como fetch, pull e push.

Branches são mesclados (merge) a um branch principal, que costuma ser o <strike>master</strike> main, que apesar do nome não tem nada de especial, é só um branch como outro qualquer.

Diferentes equipes usam diferentes maneiras de organizar, por exemplo um branch dev, um branch para produção, etc. Tem umas tentativas de padronizar isso por aí em equipes que trabalham com isso profissionalmente.

(A propósito, o histórico de modificações fica mais bonito e organizado se fizer rebase em vez de merge).

Fork é para criar um novo projeto a partir de um já existente, que se torna independente do anterior. Não é o caso no dia-a-dia de uma equipe.

Pull request é para alguém de fora da equipe contribuir com o projeto, pois exemplo com um bug fix.

Para nomear versões prontas para lançamento (releases) existem as tags (rótulos). Eu pelo menos uso com essa intenção.

Comment: Certo. Vou estudar para entender melhor os conceitos e melhores práticas. Obrigado!